# How to trigger a gitlab-ci job manually but only when tagged?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have tested `when: manual` and it works as expected. It creates a pipeline with a job that I can push play on.

But suppose I only want a job to have the manual option if a tag was created. Otherwise, skip this job.

This does not seem to work for me:

```
tag-triggered-manual-job:
  stage: publish
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^product-build-.*/
  when: manual
  script:
    - script goes here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rewrite your job with [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) it should work as excpected:

```
tag-triggered-manual-job:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - script goes here
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^product-build-.*/'
      when: manual
```

Comment: Thank you @danielnelz, I just got this a while ago. Also needed to add `allow_failure: true` so the pipeline is not marked as blocked.