Gitlab Ci - Add approval to run stage
I need to create a gitlab ci pipeline with first stage to send a email about the pipeline run to admins and then only those selected users/admins can run/approve/reject the second stage which actully does the deployment.
The pipeline anyone can run for stage 1, but for stage 2 requires selected approval.
In gitlab how to add approve/reject step on a stage.
I found a documentation related to protected environments in gitlab but thats premium gitlab.
Suggest any alternative

Does this answer your question? How to trigger a gitlab-ci job manually but only when tagged? The important point is the when: manual option.

the stage already has manual setup but I want only specific people to approve.reject the pipeline to run.

GitLab permissions Only developer (and roles above) can create a merge request, so you will need it for your developers. You may be able to use protected tags to restrict deployment to the maintainers. But it may be possible for a developer to open a MR and modify this from the .gitlab-ci.yml. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/72040853/2257664
